# Overvoltage and overcurrent protection to digital signal lines

Tags: switches, short-circuit, isolation, digital-communications, over-voltage-protection

I'm looking for a technology that protects digital signal lines like SPI, I2C, UART and general purpose I/O against overvoltage and short circuit. That is, protects the microcontroller's digital communication pins. These conditions can have an indetermined duration, so, solutions with TVS diodes would be no good solutions.

I imagined to use opto-coupling, but I came across with the issue of bidirectionality, which with opto-coupling technology is difficult to achieve. I found two other alternatives, galvanic isolation and  Detection and Surge Protection Switches.

**Galvanic isolation**: I faced the issue of bidirectionality, I saw that, normally, these ICs do not have bidirectionality along the same line. I found an IC, [ADuM1250](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADUM1250_1251.pdf), whose a good description can be found in document [AN-913](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/AN_913.pdf), but as I understand it, it is optimized for I2C communication. I'm not sure if it would be suitable for general purpose I/O pins.

**Detection and Overvoltage Protection Switches**: This technology seemed to be the most promising for my purposes. A good example is the [ADG5412F/ADG5413F](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADG5412F_5413F.pdf).

So, I have the following doubts:

1. ICs based on galvanic isolation technology, like the one I mentioned, how would they behave in case of an overvoltage? Is there a general purpose IC with galvanic isolation that has bidirectional lines? What would happen in a short-circuit situation, like a short to ground in one of the lines?
2. Is there a switch with overvoltage detection and protection that also protects against short-circuit?

Comment: this may help https://www.rugged-circuits.com/10-ways-to-destroy-an-arduino

Comment: @jsotola Nice. But, the use of PTC is strange, I always found PTC being 
 recommended to power lines. This is the first time I see it being used at general purpose digital lines

Comment: I guess a 150 Ohm resistor will protect from overcurrent, an overvoltage protection switch will protect against overvoltage and TVS diode will protect against ESD. Combining these circuits maybe is enought, I hope.